# I am trying to addon Samsung Emulator to my Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, galaxy-tab

I found this article online http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-Tab-Emulator

but I am not able to see a screen that is shown in the article. I can see AVD Manager or SDK Manager but I am not seeing available packages menu option to get to Samsung Electronics.

Please let me know how I can get this done? I use Eclipse Keplar  Version .

Thanks

Comment: you click on launch from snapshot? you can see this option in 8th step.

Comment: No The issue is I am on Android version 18 and the Samsung Device version is 8 so I can see an error message "[2013-09-28 11:30:24 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'addon_galaxy_tab_samsung_electronics_8': Unable to find base platform with API level '8'
"

Comment: http://mdid.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/android-sdk-installation-error-unable-to-find-base-platform-with-api-level/ check this.

Comment: I look at that webpage, but my issue is I dont know how to get to that screen I dont have that in the latest eclipse I use eclipse keplar version

Comment: Ok I found similar screen I am going to try what they say

Comment: I tired everything nothing makes the error go away